# placing method calls in parameters vs creating a variable and passing it

Tags: java, performance

When passing a value to a method,

1. place a method call directly in it which returns the required value to be passed
2. or create a variable and get the value in it through the same method call and place the value in parameter.

   ```
       //first approach
       methodToCall(methodReturnValue());
       //second approach
       int variable=methodReturnValue();
       methodToCall(variable);
   ```

which technique is better?

In my own opinion I think the first technique is better than the second one because the second one requires you to create an extra variable which will definitely occupy memory space. Another aspect is, creating a variable causes a CPU cycle to memory while return value is stored in register not in memory(RAM) so it also reduce memory read cycles.

Comment: You need to answer two questions: 1. Are you going to re-use the return value from that method somewhere else? If yes, store it in a variable. If no, ask yourself: 2. Is the method named in such a way that it is clear that it will return something and what that something represents? If not, variable or refactor the method. If it's clear, don't bother with the variable. **Disclaimer:** personal opinion.

Comment: Both perform a method call. Both store a variable (the second is just garbage collected at a sooner point). The question is do you need `variable` after `methodToCall` or not?

Comment: @cricket_007 variable is not needed

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 has no "additional" runtime "penalty" whatsoever; there is no variable assigned, nothing that would need further treatment.

Option 2 on the other hand is **easier to read** (as the sequence of method calls is top down, instead of right to left); and it allows you to further use that result variable; for example for tracing or other functional calls.

Thus: the answer is - there is no **better** solution here. Just different options with different pros/cons.